# How does GridDB manages table bloating\Dead rows?

Tags: griddb

GridDB follows MVCC architecture, so there are high chances that table bloating may occur at some point. So, how does GridDB manages internal bloating?

For Example, PostgreSQL manages table bloating via an internal and automated mechanism called "Auto Vacuum"